# How to catch SIGTERM properly in Docker?

Tags: bash, docker, signals

I have a docker container created by the following Dockerfile:

```
ARG TAG=latest
FROM continuumio/miniconda3:${TAG}
ARG GROUP_ID=1000
ARG USER_ID=1000
ARG ORG=my-org
ARG USERNAME=user
ARG REPO=none
ARG COMMIT=none
ARG BRANCH=none
ARG MAKEAPI=True
RUN addgroup --gid $GROUP_ID $USERNAME
RUN adduser --uid $USER_ID --disabled-password --gecos "" $USERNAME --ingroup $USERNAME
COPY . /api_maker
RUN /opt/conda/bin/pip install pyyaml psutil packaging
RUN apt install -y openssh-client git

RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
ENV GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /run/secrets/thekey"
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=thekey git clone git@github.com:$ORG/$REPO.git /repo
RUN /opt/conda/bin/python3 /api_maker/repo_setup.py $BRANCH $COMMIT
RUN /repo/root_script.sh
RUN chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /api_maker
RUN chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /repo
RUN mkdir -p /data
RUN chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /data
RUN mkdir -p /working
RUN chown -R $USERNAME:$USERNAME /working
RUN mkdir -p /opt/conda/pkgs
RUN mkdir -p /opt/conda/envs
RUN chmod -R 777 /opt/conda
RUN touch /opt/conda/pkgs/urls.txt
USER $USERNAME
RUN /api_maker/user_env_setup.sh $MAKEAPI
CMD /repo/run_api.sh $@;
```

with the following `run_api.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /repo
PROCESSES=${1:-9}
LOCAL_DOCKER_PORT=${2:-7001}
exec /opt/conda/envs/environment/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$LOCAL_DOCKER_PORT --workers=$PROCESSES restful_api:app
```

My app contains some signal handling. If I manually send `SIGTERM` to `gunicorn` (either the worker or the parent process) from inside the container, my signal handling works properly. However, it does not work right when I run `docker stop` on the container. How can I make my shell script properly forward the SIGTERM it is supposedly receiving?

Comment: Apologies, the beginning of my dockerfile is missing. Will fix when I get home.

Comment: Does changing the `CMD` to exec form `CMD ["/repo/run_api.sh"]` make any difference?

Comment: That appears to work perfectly! Many thanks, and please feel free to post it as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure the main container process is your actual application, and not a shell wrapper.

As you have the `CMD` currently, a shell invokes it.  The argument list `$@` will always be empty.  The shell parses `/repo/run_api.sh` and sees that it's followed by a semicolon, so it might need to do something else.  So even though your script correctly ends with `exec gunicorn ...` to hand off control directly to the other process, it's still running underneath a shell, and when you `docker stop` the container, it goes to the shell wrapper.

The easiest way to avoid this shell is to use an [exec form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) `CMD`:

```sh
CMD ["/repo/run_api.sh"]
```

This will cause your script to run directly, without having a `/bin/sh -c` wrapper invoking it, and when the script eventually `exec` another process, that process becomes the main process and will receive the `docker stop` signal.

Comment: Extra credit question: is there a way I can configure things so that the user can actually change the value of $PROCESSES at when running the container (not when building it)? I tried the `-e` flag, but it seems to have no effect.

Comment: Set `ENV PROCESSES=9` in the Dockerfile.  Do not set its value in the script.  You _could_ do similarly for `$LOCAL_DOCKER_PORT` but I'd recommend just hard-coding a value.